# Modal every few seconds with CyanogenMod 11 20140708-SNAPSHOT-M8-hammerhead: "Unfortunately, Google Play services has stopped"

Tags: cyanogenmod

Every so often I get this pesky dialog:

[image: screenshot with error modal]

I touch "OK" and it pops up again. This repeats until I reboot or don't use the phone for a while, then the problem clears up on its own.

Eventually I start using the phone and the problem occurs after a while again.

I used logcat and I see some stuff about a NullPointerException in some obfuscated WearableService code.

I'm using CyanogenMod 11-20140708-SNAPSHOT-M8-hammerhead. At the time of writing this is the [most recent available snapshot](https://download.cyanogenmod.org/?device=hammerhead&type=snapshot).

I've tried upgrading to the snapshot I have now, and this seemed to solve the problem for a while. I've tried wiping the cache partition and wiping the dalvik cache.

```
I/Timeline(19904): Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@428cc068 time:13198798
I/Timeline(  779): Timeline: Activity_windows_visible id: ActivityRecord{42320068 u0 com.android.settings/.SubSettings t28} time:13199067
V/Zygote  (21184): Switching descriptor 33 to /dev/null
V/Zygote  (21184): Switching descriptor 10 to /dev/null
I/ActivityManager(  779): Start proc com.google.android.gms.wearable for service com.google.android.gms/.wearable.service.WearableService: pid=21184 uid=10022 gids={50022, 3003, 1007, 1028, 1015, 1006, 3002, 3001, 3007, 2001, 3006}
D/ActivityThread(21184): handleBindApplication:com.google.android.gms.wearable
D/ActivityThread(21184): setTargetHeapUtilization:0.75
D/ActivityThread(21184): setTargetHeapMinFree:524288
I/MultiDex(21184): install
I/MultiDex(21184): MultiDexExtractor.load(/data/app/com.google.android.gms-2.apk, false)
I/MultiDex(21184): loading existing secondary dex files
I/MultiDex(21184): load found 1 secondary dex files
I/MultiDex(21184): install done
I/ProviderInstaller(21184): Insert disabled by gate 'gms:security:enable_conscrypt_in_gms_application'
D/GCM     ( 1343): GcmService start Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.INITIALIZE flg=0x10 pkg=com.google.android.gms cmp=com.google.android.gms/.gcm.GcmService } com.google.android.gms.INITIALIZE
D/assets  (21184): performGC: starting
W/dalvikvm(21184): threadid=13: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41efbce0)
E/AndroidRuntime(21184): FATAL EXCEPTION: WearableService
E/AndroidRuntime(21184): Process: com.google.android.gms.wearable, PID: 21184
E/AndroidRuntime(21184): java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(21184):    at kex.a(SourceFile:370)
E/AndroidRuntime(21184):    at kdq.a(SourceFile:390)
E/AndroidRuntime(21184):    at kef.e(SourceFile:240)
E/AndroidRuntime(21184):    at kef.a(SourceFile:270)
E/AndroidRuntime(21184):    at com.google.android.gms.wearable.service.WearableService.a(SourceFile:64)
E/AndroidRuntime(21184):    at khl.run(SourceFile:144)
E/AndroidRuntime(21184):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
E/AndroidRuntime(21184):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
E/AndroidRuntime(21184):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
E/AndroidRuntime(21184):    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
E/qcom_sensors_hal(  779): hal_process_report_ind: Bad item quality: 11 
I/Process (21184): Sending signal. PID: 21184 SIG: 9
W/InputMethodManagerService(  779): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@428bc5f0 attribute=null, token = android.os.BinderProxy@42e5b158
I/ActivityManager(  779): Process com.google.android.gms.wearable (pid 21184) has died.
W/ActivityManager(  779): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.google.android.gms/.wearable.service.WearableService in 1000ms
V/Zygote  (21225): Switching descriptor 33 to /dev/null
V/Zygote  (21225): Switching descriptor 10 to /dev/null
I/ActivityManager(  779): Start proc com.google.android.gms.wearable for service com.google.android.gms/.wearable.service.WearableService: pid=21225 uid=10022 gids={50022, 3003, 1007, 1028, 1015, 1006, 3002, 3001, 3007, 2001, 3006}
D/ActivityThread(21225): handleBindApplication:com.google.android.gms.wearable
D/ActivityThread(21225): setTargetHeapUtilization:0.75
D/ActivityThread(21225): setTargetHeapMinFree:524288
I/MultiDex(21225): install
I/MultiDex(21225): MultiDexExtractor.load(/data/app/com.google.android.gms-2.apk, false)
I/MultiDex(21225): loading existing secondary dex files
I/MultiDex(21225): load found 1 secondary dex files
I/MultiDex(21225): install done
I/ProviderInstaller(21225): Insert disabled by gate 'gms:security:enable_conscrypt_in_gms_application'
D/GCM     ( 1343): GcmService start Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.INITIALIZE flg=0x10 pkg=com.google.android.gms cmp=com.google.android.gms/.gcm.GcmService } com.google.android.gms.INITIALIZE
D/assets  (21225): performGC: starting
W/dalvikvm(21225): threadid=13: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41efbce0)
E/AndroidRuntime(21225): FATAL EXCEPTION: WearableService
E/AndroidRuntime(21225): Process: com.google.android.gms.wearable, PID: 21225
E/AndroidRuntime(21225): java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(21225):    at kex.a(SourceFile:370)
E/AndroidRuntime(21225):    at kdq.a(SourceFile:390)
E/AndroidRuntime(21225):    at kef.e(SourceFile:240)
E/AndroidRuntime(21225):    at kef.a(SourceFile:270)
E/AndroidRuntime(21225):    at com.google.android.gms.wearable.service.WearableService.a(SourceFile:64)
E/AndroidRuntime(21225):    at khl.run(SourceFile:144)
E/AndroidRuntime(21225):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
E/AndroidRuntime(21225):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
E/AndroidRuntime(21225):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
E/AndroidRuntime(21225):    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
I/Process (21225): Sending signal. PID: 21225 SIG: 9
I/ActivityManager(  779): Process com.google.android.gms.wearable (pid 21225) has died.
W/ActivityManager(  779): Service crashed 2 times, stopping: ServiceRecord{438a0f50 u0 com.google.android.gms/.wearable.service.WearableService}
```

Has anyone else run into this? Were you able to find any work-arounds? Is this more likely a hardware, gapps, or cyanogenmod problem? Where should I file a bug? Any ideas on how to further debug this?

Comment: What's your question? If it's "why is this happening?" the answer is probably, "because you're using an unstable build".

Comment: Well, [there are no "stable" CyanogenMod builds](http://www.cyanogenmod.org/blog/cyanogenmod-11-0-m6-release). I have many questions: sure, "why?", but also, "has anyone else run into this?", "were you able to find any work-arounds?", "is this more likely a hardware, gapps, or cyanogenmod problem?" (e.g., where should I file a bug), "what kinds of things should I try?", "any ideas on how to further debug this?"

Answer (score 0):

I got this issue with M10, disabling location completely solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

This helped for me (OnePlus One)

1. Go to “Settings”
2. Select “Apps”
3. Swipe left until you in the ‘All’ column
4. Click on the 3 dots in top right
5. Select “Reset app preferences”
6. Reboot phone
7. Reselect preferred launcher

via http://blog.forret.com/2015/06/getting-rid-of-google-play-services-has-stopped-on-oneplus/

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced this when doing a dirty flash from one rom (or stock) to another. A factory reset should clear this problem up. Backup your apps and wipe then restore